# Read streamfile in java

Tags: java, file, csv, filestream, filereader

I am working on comma separated value file.i want to extract first position["0" place in array] value from each raw and want to some math calculation on it.

```
csv inputfile is like this
a,b,c,d
12,32,45,76
23,45,77,56
32,34,49,28
73,92,26,68
73,36,77,26
```

for getting first position it give me error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""12"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1268)

at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:548)
    at rotation.pkg45.Rotation45.main(Rotation45.java:49)//code line no-49
```

it work fine for second and third position but for the fourth it give the same error as first.

```
 package rotation.pkg45;import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
public class Rotation45 {
 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        String filename = "bank-full2.csv";
        ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>( );
        String[] t1;
       // StringBuilder sb;
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bank2test1.csv"));     
               double a1=0.866025;
        double a2=0.5;
        double a3=-0.5;
        double a4=0.866025;
        double b1;
        double b2;
        double c1;
        double c2;          

            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            inputStream.next();  
             Scanner inputStreamm = new Scanner(file);
            inputStreamm.next();          

         while (inputStreamm.hasNext()) {   //while loop for find MEAN
            String data = inputStreamm.next();   //read each line and store in data
            String[] values = data.split(",");  //every line splited with " ; " and store each attribute in string list 

            double first = Double.parseDouble(values[1]); 


          /* no suchelementexeption  */  String data1 = inputStreamm.next();   //read each line and store in data
            String[] values1 = data1.split(",");  
            //inputStream.next();          
            double second = Double.parseDouble(values1[1]); 

            c1= ((a2*second)+(a1*first));
    c2= ((a3*first)+(a4*second));
       values1[2] = String.valueOf(c2);
        values[2] = String.valueOf(c1);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //  String newData = sb.toString();
            for (int i = 0; i<values.length ; i++) {
                    sb.append(values[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                    }
             sb.append("\n");
              for (int i = 0; i<values1.length ; i++) {
                    sb.append(values1[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                    }
            // get the new string
           // System.out.println(sb.toString());

            writer.write(sb.toString()+"\n");
                }
            writer.close();

            inputStreamm.close();


            }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
              {
            Logger.getLogger(Rotation45.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

here just for example i had extracted values[1](means second position in array like 32,45,34,..)

```
so result will be..
12,34,45,76
23,46,77,56
32,36,49,28
73,93,26,68
73,38,77,26
```

this codeis works for values[1]and value[2] not in values[0]and value[3]..why i cant understand pls help me...

Comment: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""12"** as you see in your csv file there's an extra quote before the 12 number

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I do not see any quote in the op's csv? could you say where they are?

Comment: there is no  quote like "" in the input file (bank-full2)...

Comment: when i read another file ..it give me error like "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" but file is absulatly fine.. that is mention in the code where it throws the error.

Comment: Can you please read the exception, it says couldnt parse ""12" there's a double quote at the very begining of number.

Comment: In your `while` loop you are checking `inputStreamm.hasNext()` but inside the loop you are calling `inputStreamm.next()` twice which will result in `java.util.NoSuchElementException` when after last line has already read by first `inputStreamm.next()` and second `inputStreamm.next()` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problem in your code in terms of generating exception and readability.

I rewrote your code and it is working :

```
package rotation.pkg45;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Rotation45 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filename = "bank-full2.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bank2test1.csv"));

            Scanner inputStreamm = new Scanner(file);
            inputStreamm.nextLine();

            while (inputStreamm.hasNext()) { // while loop for find MEAN
                String data = inputStreamm.nextLine(); // read each line and store in data
                String[] values = data.split(","); // every line splited with " , " and store each attribute in string list

                // double value is generating 34.0 value, and you are expecting only 34
                // double first = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
                int first = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                first = first + 2;

                values[1] = String.valueOf(first);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                // String newData = sb.toString();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    sb.append(values[i]);
                    if (i < values.length - 1) {
                        sb.append(",");
                    }
                }

                if (inputStreamm.hasNext()) { /* To handle NoSuchElementException */
                    String data1 = inputStreamm.nextLine(); // read each line and store in data
                    String[] values1 = data1.split(",");

                    // double second = Double.parseDouble(values1[1]);
                    int second = Integer.parseInt(values1[1]);
                    second = second + 1;
                    values1[1] = String.valueOf(second);

                    sb.append("\n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
                        sb.append(values1[i]);
                        if (i < values.length - 1) {
                            sb.append(",");
                        }
                    }
                }
                writer.write(sb.toString() + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();

            inputStreamm.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Rotation45.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**CSV input file:**

```
a,b,c,d
12,32,45,76
23,45,77,56
32,34,49,28
73,92,26,68
73,36,77,26
```

**CSV output file:**

```
12,34,45,76
23,46,77,56
32,36,49,28
73,93,26,68
73,38,77,26
```

---

Changes done are:

> 1. Replaced `inputStreamm.next();` with `inputStreamm.nextLine();`
> 2. Code refactored. Processing of `values` is done first and then `values1`.
> 3. Added `if (inputStreamm.hasNext())` to handle `NoSuchElementException`.
> 4. Replaced `Double.parseDouble(values1[1]);` with `Integer.parseInt(values1[1]);`, as it was generating `34.0` and you wanted `34` in your output file.

Comment: but i had make little mistake for ask my query i forgot to mention ...why i had use two time inputStreamm.next();because i want 2 values at a same time and do some mathematical operation on it...and store back to it...sry..

Comment: i edited my code pls check ..thats why i need 2 value at same time.. earlier i made some incremental step on it for mathematical simplification...but i think it was not productive way to ask..

Comment: @vivekpatel, you can divide urs code this way. 1. read file and store values in 2 dimensional array. 2. Use that 2 dimensional array and do your calculation and prepare your result. 3. Write your result to a file.

Answer (score 1):

When you read the line, it apparently returns with surrounding quotation marks, as such:

```
"12,32,45,76"
```

So when you split it, you get the following elements:

```
"12
32
45
76"
```

As you can see the first and last elements in the row are not numbers and therefore your *Double.ParseDouble(..)* call fails.

You should either modify the original string (by either substringing it or more preferably using *.reaplce("\"", "")*) or check each element after the split and then replace / trim the quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

bacause values[1]and value[2]  has quotation marks,you should String.replaceAll() quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I can notice various problems:

```
 Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
 inputStream.next();  
 Scanner inputStreamm = new Scanner(file);
 inputStreamm.next();
```

Why are you declaring and instantiating `inputStream` two times?

What are you trying to do with this:

```
        String data = inputStreamm.next();   //read each line and store in data
        String[] values = data.split(",");  //every line splited with " ; " and store each attribute in string list 
        double first = Double.parseDouble(values[1]); 
        first=first+2;
        String data1 = inputStreamm.next();   //read each line and store in data
        String[] values1 = data1.split(",");  
        //inputStream.next();          
        double second = Double.parseDouble(values1[1]); 
        second=second+1;
```

It smells repetition to me.

EDIT: I have quickly complied one program that will do the work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "src/files/text/simple.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        boolean readingHeader = true;
        String integerValues = "";
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // use comma as separator
                if(readingHeader) {
                    readingHeader = false;
                    continue;
                }
                String[] values = line.split(cvsSplitBy); // we get ints here.
                integerValues = integerValues + values[0] + ",";
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(integerValues);

    }
```

It prints: `12,23,32,73,73,`. You need to do some clean up but it will give you the idea.